# How to make the button content display vertically in WPF?

Tags: wpf, button, user-interface

Recently I installed Visual Studio 2010 and I find that the content of the sidebar button goes vertically like the below image

[image: Screenshot of vertical text for VS2010]

My question is: is there a simple way to achieve this effect in WPF?

Comment: Transform Class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.transform.aspx

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Very easy, use `LayoutTransform` and `RotateTransform`:

```
<ToggleButton Content="Members Info" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
              Click="btn_MembersInfo_Click">         
    <ToggleButton.LayoutTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
</ToggleButton.LayoutTransform>
</ToggleButton>
```

Answer (score 4):

Will need to adjust Width Height and Center

```
<Button Content="RotatedButton" Width="200" Height="100">
    <Button.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform CenterX="0" CenterY="0" Angle="90" />
    </Button.RenderTransform>
</Button>
```